# Is it possible to directly communicate between 2 React child components instead of going over their common parent

Tags: reactjs

Let's say we have a parent component and 2 child components. I know that it is possible to communicate between a child and a parent component to realize a communication path like that : child0 - parent - child1. However, is it possible to skip the parent to result in smth like child0 - child1? By doing so, it would not be necessary to rerender the parent component in order to rerender a child, which is desired in my case.

Comment: What do you mean by `communication`? Can you explain it furthermore?

Comment: You can use a central store like Redux?

Comment: For example, child0 contains multiple buttons and if you press on one, something should change in child1. The way i solved it was to set them under a common parent component. The parent component passes a callback to child0 in order to react to a button click and rerender child1 respectively. But what i now want is to directly pass the changes from child0 to child1 without going through the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pure `React`, your request is not possible to achieve. You can try to use [`Context API`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). However `Context` works the same as a state but without sending value node by node. I think you can use [`Redux`](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) for your purpose since it only updates when [`mapDispatchToProps`](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/04/02/redux-rerendering/) changes.

Comment: If you accept my answer, I will be thankful too :D